# Is a point in time: within an hour, within today, tomorrow later than tomorrow or past already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display a closing time in relative words, e.g. "You have 2 hours left to answer the poll".

What is wrong with the below? When there are e.g. 54 minutes left, it returns "54 hours".

```
    minute_diff = ((datetime_value - DateTime.current) * 24 * 60).to_i

    case 
    when minute_diff < 0 # past time
        [nil, "closed"]
    when minute_diff.between?(0, 59) # within an hour
        [minute_diff, "minutes"]
    when datetime_value.today? # today
        number_of_hours = (minute_diff / 60)
        [number_of_hours, "hours"]
    when datetime_value.to_date == DateTime.current.tomorrow.to_date # tomorrow
        [1, "day"]
    when datetime_value.to_date > DateTime.current.tomorrow.to_date # later than tomorrow
        number_of_days = (datetime_value.to_date - DateTime.current.to_date).to_i
        [number_of_days, "days"]
    end
```

(Suggestions on a better way to return relative time is much appreciated)

Comment: "it's 2 hours left" doesn't make sense, grammatically, so it's hard to advise.  These might be what you are looking for though.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Comment: @MaxWilliams Alright, the wording is now corrected. And yes I know of the DateHelper but didn't find it sufficient for my case.

Comment: What do you want to print when it's in the past?

Comment: I'm sorry to bug you with another silly mistake, but now corrected. If the returning array[0] evaluates to nil, the message will be "Closed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your second question (giving a better way), you should use what is already there.

```
if (t = DateTime.current) < datetime_value
  "You have #{distance_of_time_in_words(t, datetime_value)} left to answer the poll".
else
  "Closed"
end
```

If you want to handle l18n, my favorite is the ["twitter-cldr" gem](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb).

Comment: Is there any way to apply I18n on this, as the returning value is one single string?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the rails date helpers ARE sufficient for this.

```
if datetime_value > 0
  s = "You have #{time_ago_in_words(datetime_value)} left to answer the poll"
else
  s = "Closed"
end
```

Comment: The problem with those helpers is that it's hard to translate, because the returning value is one single string :(  That''s why I return the time value and name of the time unit separately. But as I didn't mention anytning about I18n in the question, your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: I guess `datetime_value > 0` is always `true`, right?

Comment: They aren't hard to translate, though. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-other-built-in-methods-that-provide-i18n-support